# The polynomial of a square matrix and its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

> For any polynomial
>
> $$p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_k x^k$$
>
> and any square matrix $A$, polynomial $p(A)$ is defined as
>
> $$p(A) = a_0 I + a_1 A + \cdots + a_k A^k$$
>
> Show that if $v$ is any eigenvector of $A$ and $\chi_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $\chi_A(A) v = 0$. Deduce that if $A$ is diagonalizable then $\chi_A(A)$ is the zero matrix.

I don't get "if $v$ is any eigenvector of $A$ and $\chi_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $\chi_A(A)v = 0$". I have gotten $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $p(A)$, but how do I continue?

Comment: Do you want some of your subscripts to be powers?

Comment: Yes I edited it.

Comment: Do you know that it is Cayley Hamilton theorem (which can be extended to non diagonalizable matrices) ?

Comment: You are a little cheating: **you have asked the very same question 2 days ago** (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2284135), and you don't mention it...

Comment: It is not acceptable to repost the same question twice, see this [meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26282/is-double-posting-allowed-if-a-question-is-not-answered-after-some-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: Observe that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$, then

$$
\chi_A(A)v=\sum_{i=0}^k a_iA^iv=\left(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\lambda^i\right)v=\chi_A(\lambda)v=0
$$

Comment: But it doesn't go to zero

Comment: @stedmoama What do you mean by this remark ?

Comment: Remember that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\chi_A(\lambda)=0$.

Comment: @stedmoama Attempt to answer to our questions.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with v just that  $ χ_A(λ)=0$ is always true?

Comment: It does have a lot to do with $v$ since otherwise, you don't get $\lambda^i$, since $v$ is an eigenvector, $A^iv=\lambda^iv$.

Comment: I will pay attention to that thank you!